# Elementor custom Query with ACF fields to show matching woocommerce products custom fields

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I am trying to show custom fields of some products using elementor custom query. The products are coming just fine. But they have **usage** custom fields matching custom conditions. Have a look at this image to understand the situation[image: Problem Statement Image 1]

As you see, the **usage** will show as per the conditions, if all conditions are false, default usage will be shown. Now the usage is something like this, weekly 3 times morning only or daily both times, have a look at the next image and you will understand.
[image: Usage examples for Problem Statement]

Now I have a table like this:

```
         Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday
Morning

Evening
```

So in **first cell** I want to show all the products that have **Day 1 use as Morning** and fill the entire table similarly.

I am querying the products for monday morning with this code :

```
function monday_morning_only($query_args){

$id_array = return_current_product_ids();
$query_args['post__in'] = $id_array;

$row_index = 0;
$meta_key_for_usage = 'personal_usage_condition_based_'.$row_index.'_custom_daily_usage_';
$query_args['meta_key'] = $meta_key_for_usage.'day_1';
$query_args['meta_value'] = array('Morning only','Morning and Evening');
$query_args['meta_compare'] = 'IN';

return $query_args;
}
```

This works, but shows products matching **1st condition only** as I hardcoded the `$row_index` variable to 0. I also wrote a function to return the matching row_index, but how can I put row_index for each product inside this query? Or should I query separately and merge results? Or is there any better way?  Please share your knowledge and guide me to solve this problem. Thanks.